# Cant access data retrieved from query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my query:

```
$userInfo = DB::table('userinfo')
                    ->where('user_id', $user->id)
                    ->where('app_id', $appId)
                    ->select('age_id','sex_id')->get();
```

When I am trying to display age_id:

```
dd($userInfo['age_id']);
```

It says "Undefined index: age_id"
Basically I have to use this age_id for another query, but I cannot figure out how to.

Comment: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#retrieving-results)

Comment: I read it, could not get any help from the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `get` method on the query builder like that it will return multiple rows rather than a single row. You could do something like this

```
foreach ($userInfo as $row) {
    echo $row->age_id;
}
```

Alternatively if you're expecting only one result to be returned you could use `first`.

```
$userInfo = DB::table('table')
    // Your wheres
    ->first();
if ($userInfo) {
    echo $userInfo->age_id;
}
```

Bear in mind this would add `limit 1` to your query. If nothing was found then `null` would be returned.